# How to make excel file password-protected in apex?

Tags: apex, visualforce, api, callout

I have visualforce page which is downloaded as .xls file using contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#excelFile.xls". I want to make this file as password protected. Is there any way to make excel file password-protected?

Comment: @Samir The 'possible duplicate' message is automatically generated when you vote to close as duplicate. Typing it out manually doesn't do too much.

Comment: The Flying Saucer Render Engine is NOT used to export Excel Files, so my answer referenced above does not apply to this question although I'd expect the same principles to generally be at play.